# How do you say 'video which has not been seen by me from start to finish yet' in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find easy short way how to describe video (or book even) which I looked at but didn't finish.

Comment: partly reviewed

Comment: I just ***skimmed*** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unfinished
>
> unseen
>
> unwatched
>
> in-progress
>
> continue
>
> reading
>
> watching

Answer (score 0):

Not quite one word, but you can say

> I have not watched the video right through yet.

And this

> I have not finished reading the book.

Comment: In my AmE dialect **watch a movie right through** means to watch all of the movie *in one sitting*.

Comment: @TRomano OP does say "from start to finish". That's the usual way to watch a video, but a book can be picked up and put down.